# Scribus: how to force sign in calcuated numeric fields?

Tags: script, scribus, formatting

I'm new to Scribus, and using it to make an interactive PDF. I have several fields that are calculating integer values based on a custom calculation script. Now I would like to make sure that positive values show up with a prefixed "+" sign (currently they do not). What's the easiest way to do that? (Perhaps some field format custom JavaScript?)

Comment: it's a python script for layout or a js script for an interactive pdf? ... i can help, if it's a python script for layout...

Comment: @a.l.e: Thanks for the comment. I'm talking about a feature for an interactive PDF (so JavaScript could be a solution, or maybe there's some other way). Adding that to my question.